# e.g. why the devcpp 5.11 debugging function encounters endl can't next step

Tags: c++, debugging

When I use the devcpp 5.11 , the debugging function couldn't run normally.when it encounters "endl" can't next step. if dont use #define endl "\n" , how to solve.

```
#include <iostream>
//#define endl "\n"
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int j = 1000;
    // cout << "hello world" << endl;
    
    for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        cout << i << endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

if dont use #define endl "\n" , how to solve.

Comment: `std::endl` is a function so debugger wants to step into it.  Just use the recommended style ` std::cout << i << "\n"`.  using `endl` is not needed in most cases anyway and using `#define` to change behavior of code is just plain evil. And side note stop using `using namespace std;`

Comment: When including *any* standard header, you are not allowed to `#define` any name from the standard library. And `endl` is one of those. This is one of the reasons why most macros use `UPPERCASE_NAMES`.

Comment: @PepijnKramer 
Thank you for answering my question,I had known your words, but when I use vs2022 or vscode, the debugging function could run normally even if it encounters `endl`，I want to know this.